# Korma - join on a sub select but how do I specify an alias?

Tags: clojure, korma, sqlkorma

I would like to assign an alias to the subselect in this query:

```
(->
  (korma/select* table_a)
  (korma/join
   (korma/subselect table_b
                    (korma/fields :id (korma/raw "COUNT(*) AS count"))
                    (korma/group :id))
   (= :id :id)))
```

This is the sql I am looking to create:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_b GROUP BY id) AS b b.id = id;
```

But at the moment sql korma just generates:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_b GROUP BY id) id = id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to define the sub-select as a separate entity, see below:

```
(korma/defentity sub-select
             (korma/table (korma/subselect table_b
                                           (korma/fields :id(korma/raw "COUNT(*) AS count"))
                                           (korma/group :id)) :b))

(->
  (korma/select* table_a)
  (korma/join sub-select (= :b.id :id)))
```

Which generates the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM table_b GROUP BY id) a.id = id;
```